# Why does "find" produce string type?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a learner, I work in Python 3.7.

As I understand, the find function is supposed to indicate an index position of a string.

It does just that when my input is a straight string like

```
myString='Blabla<body>blabla'.
```

now

```
myString.find('<body>')
```

returns 6.
Awesome.
But when I import the string from a webpage, I get the error

```
TypeError: argument should be integer or bytes-like object, not 'str'
```

I could not agree more, but I do not get why the argument is `str` in the first place.

My code:

```
import ssl, urllib.request
url = 'http://help.websiteos.com/websiteos/example_of_a_simple_html_page.htm'

response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
Content = response.read()
startposition = Content.find('<body>')
print(startposition)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Content` is of type `bytes`, so the argument to `Content.find` must be `bytes` or `int`, but `'<body>'` is of type `str`. So, you got mismatched types.

How to fix: convert the `str` to `bytes`:

```
Content.find(b'<body>')
```

Comment: OK, it works, thanks a lot. I still need to understand the reason though. Why is Content in this code by default of type bytes?

Comment: Because bytes are what are transmitted over the net, saved to your filesystem etc. Python strings (python 3) are unicode strings, not bytes sequences.  You may want to read this for more about bytes and unicode: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Answer (score 1):

> I do not get why the argument is 'str' in the first place.

Because that's what you passed: `'<body>'` is a literal `str` object. And before you ask, `Content` is a `bytes` object which has to be decoded (using the encoding that *should* be declared in the response) to get a proper string.

Now a much simpler solution - which is recommanded by the `urllib` doc itself - is to use the 3rd-part python-requests lib, that will take care of those annoying details for you.

Also if you want to parse HTML, by all means use a proper HTML parser (BeautifulSoup is the recommanded choice if you're having to deal with possibly malformed html, which is by far the most common case).

Answer (score 0):

Content here is a bytes object. You're trying to search a string through a bytes object. Convert Content to a string by changing the line

```
Content = response.read()
```

to

```
Content = str(response.read())
```

Comment: The diagnostic seems good but the cure is plain wrong - you can't just pass a `bytes` to `str()` and expect to get something sensible, you have to _decode_ the bytes to unicode (str), which also requires knowing the encoding.

Comment: Ah I see, I had assumed it was a trivial question to read the encoded site and overlooked the decoding. My bad